Proof of a Real Field
I'm looking at Rudin Analysis (3rd) and it says there is an existence theorem:
(1.19) There exists an ordered field R which has the least-upper-bound property. Moreover, R contains Q as a subfield. The proof is rather long and tedious and is in the appendix.
Issue is, my pdf didn't have an appendix at the back (I only found a Bibliography and Index) and I couldn't find the proof online. If someone can link where a proof can be found that'd be appreciated.

It is the field of real numbers. I'm not sure why that would be long and tedious to be honest.

@freakish This theorem is about the existence of $\mathbb{R}$, which is very non trivial. Giving a rigorous definition (for example using Dedekind cuts) and verifying all the required axioms is indeed long and tedious. But I always recommend to read it at least once.

OP, one book that I like is Spivak's calculus book. The proof appears at the end of the book.

@Mark define "very non trivial" and "long and tedious". Seriously, that is literally fundamentals of mathematics, the entrance to any "above high school" mathematics. If someone thinks that Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences are tedious and hard, then I feel sorry for that person. The real maths just begins there.

@freakish Real numbers are a fundamental topic, but not their actual definition. Here in calculus courses we just assume the reals exist (intuitively thought as a real line) and accept their axioms just as axioms. I always tell my students that if we have time by the end of the course, maybe I'll say a few words about the rigorous definition, but it never happens. So every time I just give them a reference to Spivak's book, for those who are interested. (sadly, very few of them do) But that happens at the end of the course, not at the beginning.

@Mark anegdots about students (most of whom are lazy and have zero talent for maths) aren't really relevant. Again, construction of reals is fundamental. Their construction is seriously trivial compared to what real maths deals with.

@freakish Not that I disagree, I just finished checking exams, and I don't even want to start talking about what BS many of them write. But that's not the point. Dedekind cuts are not taught in many calculus courses because they are a bit more advanced. What you want, to start a Bachelor's degree from learning research level math? That's BS. Saying you feel sorry for that person is a very not nice statement, and I'm being soft here. We have no idea what is OP's level. (though I'm not surprised)

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (3rd edition),
Theorem 1.19 is proved in the Appendix, which is on page 17 at the end of chapter 1
(not at the end of the entire book).
